# Why is lint giving a warning ineffectual assignment to (ineffassign)

Tags: go, lint

Getting a lint warning `ineffectual assignment to "cfg"` at line `cfg := &utils.Config{}`. Why is that ?

```
    cfg := &utils.Config{}
    env := os.Getenv("TEST")
    if strings.EqualFold(env, "INT") {
        cfg = utils.GetIntConfig()
    } else {
        cfg = utils.GetConfig()
    }

    cgw.Cgw(cfg)
```

Comment: `ineffectual assignment to "cfg"` means that the assignment to cfg has no effect, as you unconditionaly overwrite it later.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

After the following `if` statement, `cfg` is written, thus the value assigned to `cfg` using `cfg := &utils.Config{}` is never used. You are using an assignment where a declaration would do.

```
var cfg *utils.Config
...
```

Comment: Alright, `var cfg *utils.Config` worked. Thanks. It was needed a declaration only.

Comment: @Ishmeet, note that the linter wasn't forcing you to use a `var` declaration; instead it hinted at that you might have a bug in your code—because the first assignment could be way more involved like assigning the return value of some function call which would return a value inintialized in a complicated way, and possibly depending on some input data.